# How to deploy ASP.NET MVC application with devexpress components to Azure websites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, devexpress, web-deployment

Is there a way to deploy asp net application with dexexpress components other than using virtual machine with installed libs on it? 
I want to deploy it to azure websites but get an error that .dll are missing (dont get that error during debugging on localhost where devexpress installed).

Answer (score 1):

Be sure, that you marked the referenced assemblies that you want to publish on the vm as "copy local = true". You can find that option in the properties of a reference.

The output folder of your web app will be automatically copied over to azure websites. For more information how web pages are packaged have a look [How to: Create a Web Deployment Package in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these options:

- Find a NuGet package which includes the dll's you need. I don't know which components you use but NuGet contains a lot of packages -> https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=devexpress
- Include the dll's you need in a 3thPartyLib in your project and then reference these assemblies (with copy local = true) from your project.

Be sure to include the license file in your deployment.